# Interpretation for the tiny change in area of a flask

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, area

[image]

lets say we have round conical flask I am trying to see what a tiny change in area would be like? someone told me it is:

$$dA= \frac{2\pi r}{cos\theta}dl$$
where theta is the side slant angle of the flask and dl is the depth.
I know that the area of a tiny ring is 2 π r times thickness I dont understand why the thickness is dl/cos?

Comment: You want the area of a frustum of a cone. What is $l$ here?

Comment: lets say h is the whole height of the flask then l would be the distance  from the top to a certain point (depth).

Comment: Ah, $l$ is the height — usually, it represents the slant height, which is what we want. So $\text{height} =( \text{slant height})\sin\theta$, so you should have $\sin\theta$, not $\cos\theta$, assuming $\theta$ is the angle at the base. If it’s the complementary angle, then $\cos\theta$ is correct.

Comment: side slant angle is not that angle but I get answer thanks